# Why am I getting a JWT must be provided error in Render Console?

Tags: cookies, jwt, fetch, render, session-cookies

I'm trying to make a fetch request but I keep getting a jwt must be provided error. I've tried a number of things but keep getting this error. For some reason the cookie isn't being sent to the server. I can sign into the app so the cors policy should be fine and the token is being passed to allow sing in but I just can't access the room which is controlled by the handleplay function. Can someone take a look at this and let me know what the issue could be?

Thanks,

Nick

I've read, tried a number of methods, done as much as anyone can.

error in Render log

```
Aug 2 01:08:20 PM  (node:65) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided
Aug 2 01:08:20 PM      at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:53:17)
Aug 2 01:08:20 PM      at joinRoom (/opt/render/project/src/server/controllers/roomsController.js:78:30)
Aug 2 01:08:20 PM      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
Aug 2 01:08:20 PM      at next (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
Aug 2 01:08:20 PM      at Route.dispatch (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
Aug 2 01:08:20 PM      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
Aug 2 01:08:20 PM      at /opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
Aug 2 01:08:20 PM      at param (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
Aug 2 01:08:20 PM      at param (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:376:14)
Aug 2 01:08:20 PM      at Function.process_params (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:421:3)
```

Index.js - making the fetch calls.

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import './style.css';
import { TypeAnimation } from 'react-type-animation';
import AuthService from '../../utils/auth';
import WinVid from '../win/vid';
import MissVid from '../miss/vid';


function GlobalRiddleMenu({ onWebcamVisibilityChange, props }) {
  const webcamRef = useRef(null);
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [facingMode, setFacingMode] = useState('user');
  const [isWebcamVisible, setIsWebcamVisible] = useState(false);
  const [roomRiddle, setRoomRiddle] = useState('');
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(null);
  const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState(null);
  const [isAnswerCorrect, setIsAnswerCorrect] = useState(false);
  const [isAnswerIncorrect, setIsAnswerIncorrect] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Call the function passed in through the props whenever isWebcamVisible changes
    onWebcamVisibilityChange(isWebcamVisible);
  }, [isWebcamVisible]);

  const handleCapture = async () => {
    const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
    setImage(imageSrc);
  };

  const hideVideo = () => {
    setIsAnswerCorrect(false);
  };

  const hideMissVideo = () => {
    setIsAnswerIncorrect(false);
  };


  const handleUpload = async () => {
    if (image) {
      const blob = await fetch(image).then(res => res.blob());

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', blob, 'photo.jpg');

      try {
        const res = await fetch('https://bringme.onrender.com/api/upload', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
          credentials: 'include',
         
        });

        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }

        const data = await res.json();
        const answerResult = data.message;
        if (answerResult === "Correct") {
          setIsAnswerCorrect(true);
        } else {
          setIsAnswerIncorrect(true);
        }

      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  const switchCamera = () => {
    setFacingMode(prevState => prevState === 'user' ? 'environment' : 'user');
  };

  const fetchRiddle = async () => {
  
    try {
      const res = await fetch('https://bringme.onrender.com/api/rooms', {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
      });

      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }

      const rooms = await res.json();

      // Find the 'global' room
      const globalRoom = rooms.find(room => room.roomName.toLowerCase() === 'global');

      if (!globalRoom) {
        throw new Error('Global room not found');
      }

      setRoomRiddle(globalRoom.currentRiddle);
      // Fetch timeLeft from server
      const timeLeft = globalRoom.timeLeft;
      console.log(timeLeft);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRiddle();
    const riddleTimerId = setInterval(() => {
      fetchRiddle();
    }, 3000);

    let countdownTimerId;
    if (timeLeft !== null) {
      countdownTimerId = setInterval(() => {
        setTimeLeft(prevTime => prevTime - 1);
      }, 3000);
    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(riddleTimerId);
      clearInterval(countdownTimerId);
    }
  }, [timeLeft]);

  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~JoinRoom~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  const handlePlayNow = async () => {
    const token = Cookies.get('token'); // Get the user's authentication token from the cookie
    if (!token) {
      // Handle the case when the token is missing or not available
      console.log('User not logged in');
      // redirect to signup if not logged in
      window.location.href = '/signup';
      return;
    }

    try {
      const res = await fetch('https://bringme.onrender.com/api/rooms', {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, // Include the token in the Authorization header
        },
      });

      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }

      const rooms = await res.json();

      // Find the 'global' room
      const globalRoom = rooms.find(room => room.roomName.toLowerCase() === 'global');

      if (!globalRoom) {
        throw new Error('Global room not found');
      }

      const joinRes = await fetch(`https://bringme.onrender.com/api/rooms/join-room/${globalRoom._id}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, // Include the token in the Authorization header
        },
      });

      if (!joinRes.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to join the global room');
      }

      const joinData = await joinRes.json();
      console.log('Joined room:', joinData);
      setIsWebcamVisible(true); // Show webcam after successfully joining room
      setRoomId(globalRoom._id);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~LeaveRoom~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  const handleLeaveRoom = async () => {
    if (!AuthService.loggedIn() || !roomId) {
      console.log('User not logged in or not in room');
      console.log(roomId);
      return;
    }

    try {
      const token = Cookies.get('token'); // Get the user's authentication token from the cookie
      const leaveRes = await fetch(`https://bringme.onrender.com/api/rooms/leave-room/${roomId}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include'
  
      });

      if (!leaveRes.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to leave the room');
      }

      const leaveData = await leaveRes.json();
      console.log('Left room:', leaveData);
      setRoomId(null);
      setIsWebcamVisible(false);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleCloseImage = () => {
    setImage("");
  };

  const handleImageClick = async () => {
    try {
      await handleUpload();
      handleCloseImage();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error handling image click:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container my-1">
      <div className="text-container">
        <h2 className="riddle-prompt">Solve the Riddle!</h2>
        <span className="riddle-description">
          <TypeAnimation
            key={roomRiddle}
            sequence={[
              roomRiddle
            ]}
            wrapper="span"
            cursor={true}
          />
        </span>
        {!isWebcamVisible && (
          <button className="play-now-button play-btn" onClick={handlePlayNow}>
            Guess Now!
          </button>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="cam-container">
        {isAnswerCorrect ? (
          <div onClick={hideVideo}>
            <WinVid />
          </div>
        ) : isAnswerIncorrect ? (
          <div onClick={hideMissVideo}>
            <MissVid />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <>
            {isWebcamVisible && (
              <>
                <Webcam
                  audio={false}
                  ref={webcamRef}
                  screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
                  videoConstraints={{ facingMode }}
                  onClick={handleCapture}
                />
                <div className="profile-stats media-btn-container">
                  <button onClick={switchCamera} className="media-btn">Switch Camera</button>
                  <button onClick={handleLeaveRoom} className="media-btn">Leave Room</button>
                </div>
                {
                  image && (
                    <div className="imageSubmit">
                      <img onClick={handleImageClick} src={image} alt="Captured" className="image" />
                      <div className="newPhoto-btn">
                        <button onClick={handleCloseImage} id='newPhoto' className="media-btn profile-stats">New Photo</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )
                }
              </>
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GlobalRiddleMenu;
```

Auth service on the client side

```
import decode from 'jwt-decode';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

class AuthService {
  getProfile() {
    return decode(this.getToken());
  }

  getUserId() {
    return localStorage.getItem('userId');
  }

  loggedIn() {
    const userId = this.getUserId();

    return !!userId;
  }

  isTokenExpired(token) {
    try {
      const decoded = decode(token);
      if (decoded.exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
        return true;
      } else return false;
    } catch (err) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  getToken() {
    return Cookies.get('token');
  }

  async login(credentials) {
    const response = await fetch('https://bringme.onrender.com/api/auth/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':"*"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
      credentials: 'include',
    });
  
    const data = await response.json();
  
    if (response.ok) {
      // Save token to cookie and return userId and token
      Cookies.set('token', data.token);
      return { userId: data.userId, token: data.token };
    } else {
      // Throw an error if login was unsuccessful
      console.error('Server response:', data);
      throw new Error(data.error);
    }
  }

  loginStep2(twofaToken) {
    const loginStep2VerificationToken = this.getLoginStep2VerificationToken();
    fetch('https://bringme.onrender.com/api/auth/loginStep2', {
      
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':"*"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        twofaToken,
        loginStep2VerificationToken,
        credentials: 'include',
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Failed to verify login step 2');
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const { token } = data;
        if (token) {
          Cookies.set('token', token);
          window.location.assign('/');
        } else {
          throw new Error('Login Step 2 verification failed');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }

  getLoginStep2VerificationToken() {
    return Cookies.get('login_step2_verification_token');
  }

  removeLoginStep2VerificationToken() {
    Cookies.remove('login_step2_verification_token');
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('userId');
    Cookies.set('token', null);
    Cookies.remove('login_step2_verification_token');
    window.location.assign('/');
  }
}

const AuthServiceInstance = new AuthService();

export default AuthServiceInstance;
```

Rooms controller

```
const { Rooms } = require('../models');
const { Players } = require('../models');
const { User } = require('../models');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


module.exports = {
  // Get all rooms
  async getRooms(req, res) {
    try {
      const rooms = await Rooms.find();
      res.json(rooms);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  },

  //Get a single room
  async getSingleRoom(req, res) {
    try {
      const room = await Rooms.findById(req.params.roomId);
      if (!room) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: 'no singles' });
      }
      res.json(room);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  },

  // Create a new room
  async createRoom(req, res) {
    try {
      const room = await Rooms.create(req.body);
      res.json(room);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  },

  // Updates by roomID
  async updateRoom(req, res) {
    try {
      const room = await Rooms.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.roomId }, req.body, { new: true, runValidators: true })
        .select('-__v');

      if (!room) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: 'No update' });
      }

      res.json(room);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  },

  // Delete room
  async deleteRoom(req, res) {
    try {
      const room = await Rooms.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.roomId });

      if (!room) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: 'No delete' });
      }

      res.json({ message: 'Room deleted!' })
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  },

  // Join room


  async joinRoom(req, res) {
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    const username = decodedToken.user.username;
    const userId = decodedToken.user._id;
    const roomId = req.params.roomId;
  
    // Find the user
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }
  
    // Find the room
    const room = await Rooms.findById(roomId);
    if (!room) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Room not found" });
    }
  
    // Find the current player of the user
    const player = await Players.findOne({ _id: { $in: user.players } });

  
    if (player) {
      // If the player is already in the room, just return a message
      if (player.currentRoom && player.currentRoom.toString() === roomId) {
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Already in the room" });
      }
  
      // Remove the player from the user's players array
      user.players.pull(player._id);
      await user.save();
  
      // Delete the player
      await Players.findByIdAndDelete(player._id);
    }
  
    // Create a new player for the user in the room
    const newPlayer = new Players({
      name: username,
      user: userId,
      currentRoom: roomId,
    });
  
    await newPlayer.save();
  
    // Add the new player to the user's players array
    user.players.push(newPlayer._id);
    await user.save();
  
    // Add the new player to the room
    room.players.push(newPlayer._id);
    await room.save();
  
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully joined the room", player: newPlayer });
  },

  async leaveRoom(req, res) {
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    const userId = decodedToken.user._id;
    const roomId = req.params.roomId;

    // Find the user
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }
    // Find the room
    const room = await Rooms.findById(roomId);
    if (!room) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Room not found" });
    }

    // Find the player of the user
    const player = await Players.findOne({ _id: { $in: user.players } });
    if (!player) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Player not found" });
    }

    // Remove the player from the room's players array
    room.players.pull(player._id);
    await room.save();

    // Update the user's score and games played
    user.totalScore += player.score;
    user.currentScore += player.score;
    user.gamesPlayed++;
    await user.save();

    // Remove the player from the user's players array
    user.players.pull(player._id);
    await user.save();

    // Delete the player
    await Players.findByIdAndDelete(player._id);

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully left the room" });
  },

  
};
```

Authcontroller

```
const User = require('../models/User');
const { authenticator } = require('otplib');
const qrcode = require('qrcode');
const passport = require('passport');

const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('login', { session: false }, async (err, user, info) => {
    if (err || !user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: 'Invalid email or password',
      });
    }

    if (!user.twofaEnabled) {
      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
          user: {
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email,
            _id: user._id,
            session_id: Date.now(),
          },
        },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24 } // Token expires in 24 hours (60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours)
      );

      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      console.log(decoded);

      const sessionExpiresAt = new Date(decoded.user.session_id + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000); // 24 hours in milliseconds
      // const sessionExpiresAt = new Date(decoded.user.session_id + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 + process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN_SMOL * 1000);

      await User.updateOne(
        { _id: user._id },
        {
          $set: {
            session_id: decoded.user.session_id,
            session_expires_at: sessionExpiresAt,
          },
        }
      );

      res.cookie('token', token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
      });

      return res.json({
        message: 'Login successful',
        twofaEnabled: false,
        token: token,
        userId: user._id,
      });
    } else {
      return res.json({
        message: 'Please complete 2-factor authentication',
        twofaEnabled: true,
        loginStep2VerificationToken: jwt.sign(
          {
            loginStep2Verification: { email: user.email },
          },
          process.env.JWT_SECRET,
          { expiresIn: 60 * 15 } // Token expires in 15 minutes (60 seconds * 15 minutes)
        ),
        userId: user._id,
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
};

const loginStep2 = async (req, res) => {
  let loginStep2VerificationToken = null;
  try {
    loginStep2VerificationToken = jwt.verify(
      req.body.loginStep2VerificationToken,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: 'You are not authorized to perform login step-2',
    });
  }

  const token = req.body.twofaToken.replaceAll(' ', '');
  const user = await User.findOne({
    email: loginStep2VerificationToken.loginStep2Verification.email,
  });
  if (!authenticator.check(token, user.twofaSecret)) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: 'OTP verification failed: Invalid token',
    });
  } else {
    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        user: {
          username: user.username,
          email: user.email,
          _id: user._id,
          session_id: Date.now(),
        },
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24 } // Token expires in 24 hours (60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours)
    );

    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    const sessionExpiresAt = new Date(decoded.user.session_id + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000); // 24 hours in milliseconds
    // const sessionExpiresAt = new Date(decoded.user.session_id + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 + process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN_SMOL * 1000);

    await User.updateOne(
      { _id: user._id },
      {
        $set: {
          session_id: decoded.user.session_id,
          session_expires_at: sessionExpiresAt,
        },
      }
    );

    res.cookie('token', token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
    });

    return res.json({
      message: 'OTP verification successful',
      token: token,
      userId: user._id,
    });
  }
};

const generate2faSecret = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.user.email });

  if (user.twofaEnabled) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: '2FA already verified and enabled',
      twofaEnabled: user.twofaEnabled,
    });
  }

  const secret = authenticator.generateSecret();
  user.twofaSecret = secret;
  await user.save();
  const appName = 'Bring Me';

  const qrImageDataUrl = await qrcode.toDataURL(
    authenticator.keyuri(user.email, appName, secret)
  );

  return res.json({
    message: '2FA secret generation successful',
    secret: secret,
    qrImageDataUrl: qrImageDataUrl,
    twofaEnabled: user.twofaEnabled,
  });
};

const verifyOtp = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.user.email });
  if (user.twofaEnabled) {
    return res.json({
      message: '2FA already verified and enabled',
      twofaEnabled: user.twofaEnabled,
    });
  }

  const token = req.body.token.replaceAll(' ', '');
  if (!authenticator.check(token, user.twofaSecret)) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: 'OTP verification failed: Invalid token',
      twofaEnabled: user.twofaEnabled,
    });
  } else {
    user.twofaEnabled = true;
    await user.save();

    return res.json({
      message: 'OTP verification successful',
      twofaEnabled: user.twofaEnabled,
    });
  }
};

const disable2fa = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.user.email });
  user.twofaEnabled = false;
  user.twofaSecret = '';
  await user.save();

  return res.json({
    message: '2FA disabled successfully',
    twofaEnabled: user.twofaEnabled,
  });
};

const logout = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    await User.updateOne(
      { _id: decoded.user._id },
      { $set: { session_id: null } }
    );

    res.json({
      message: 'User logged out',
      token: '',
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error occurred during logout' });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  login,
  loginStep2,
  generate2faSecret,
  verifyOtp,
  disable2fa,
  logout,
};
```

updatesession middleware

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/User'); // path to your User model

// This middleware updates the user's session_id and session_expires_at in the database
const updateSessionMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        // assuming the decoded JWT is stored in req.user
        const decoded = jwt.verify(req.cookies.token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        const userId = decoded.user._id;
        // create a new session id
        const newSessionId = Date.now();

        // calculate the new session expiration time
        const sessionExpiresAt = new Date(new Date().getTime() + parseInt(process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN_SMOL) * 60 * 1000);

        // update the user in the database
        await User.updateOne(
            { _id: userId },
            {
                $set: {
                    session_id: newSessionId,
                    session_expires_at: sessionExpiresAt
                }
            }
        );

        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send({ error: 'An error occurred while updating the session.' });
    }
};

module.exports = updateSessionMiddleware;
```

checksession middleware

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/User');

const checkSession = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // Extract the token from the headers
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    console.log(authHeader);

    if (!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid session. Please log in again.' });
    }

    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

    // Decode the token
    let decoded;
    try {
      decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid session. Please log in again.' });
    }

    // Fetch the user from the database
    const user = await User.findById(decoded?.user?._id);

    // Check that the user and session_id in the token match the user's session_id in the database
    if (!user || user.session_id !== decoded?.user?.session_id) {
      // If they don't match, reject the request
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid session. Please log in again.' });
    }

    // If they do match, allow the request to proceed
    next();

  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server Error' });
  }
};

module.exports = checkSession;
```

Comment: Can you include the code making the request and the response you get from the web server?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey guys, I just updated the question so the issue should be reproducible. Let me know if you have additional questions. Thanks.